# How to reach apps in minikube from outside?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, minikube, eclipse-hono

I want to use the eclipse hono application in a minikube kubernetes cluster. In my usecase I need to reach services from the outside but all services are running on the localhost...how can I change that? Thanks in advice!

Comment: I would suggest looking into using a ingress-controller to expose your services.
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.